# Criterion for series to have convergent rearrangement

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to find a criterion for $\sum a_n$ to have a convergent rearrangement in terms of $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ where $p_n=\frac{1}{2}(|a_n|+a_n)$ and $q_n=\frac{1}{2}(|a_n|-a_n).$

First off, if $\sum a_n$ converges, then clearly it has a convergent rearrangement. So it seems like we're only concerned with finding a criterion for $\sum a_n$ to have a convergent rearrangement given that $\sum a_n$ diverges.

My next thought is that if $\sum a_n$ diverges and $a_n$ does not tend to $0,$ then we can't find a convergent rearrangement. Now, if $a_n\rightarrow0$ and $a_n$ has only finitely many positive or negative terms, then I can't see there being a convergent rearrangement (take $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ for example).

So my conjecture is that if $\sum a_n$ diverges and $a_n\rightarrow0$ and $a_n$ has infinitely many positive and negative terms, then $\sum a_n$ has a convergent rearrangement. However, I don't really know how to put this in terms of $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n.$